# I need a book about different government types and their history to create believeable countries. Could you recommend me some?

Tags: politics, government

As I stated, I want to do a proper research. I'm interested in pretty general stuff, but I want it to posess some factual values. I'd be glad for your help.

Comment: I think you'd need to detail a bit more what you need. There's just too much books to be able to suggest one that pinpoints what you want. This aside, have you looked at the [list of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources)? There are some government stuff in there.

Comment: I want to browse through different types and see when they were introduced, who did this and how did they work. If possible, I'd like to start as early as it's possible. Perhaps how villages evolved into towns and how they were ruled etc.? I'd like to see different approaches to monarchy, how it evolved, where are the roots of modern democracy etc.

Comment: As it stands, your question is ridiculously broad. Just the Roman empire alone would take up book cases. [Primatology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primatology), [Ancient governments](https://whatspolitics.weebly.com/ancient-political-systems.html), [More Ancient govenrments](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/chapters/mono/10.4324/9781003235798-9/governments-ancient-world-jana-kirchner-andrew-mcmichael), [modern political theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/world-government/). But it's not just about government, it's about the resources, weather, competitors, invaders and general survival.

Comment: Not to mention disease, superstition, maladaptive strategies, chance, betrayal, alliances, sabotage, misfortune. Never forget inbreeding in ancient Egypt mucking-up dynasties. **Very big subject for a single book to cover.**

Comment: You're right, but don't you have anything general? Like basic info on politics without many details, so I can start somewhere and see directions I'd like to follow?

Comment: Yeah, the third link "More Ancient governments". (Except spelt worse).

Comment: Thanks! I'll browse through them <3

Comment: Charles de Secondat, baron de [Montesquieu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_de_Secondat,_Baron_de_Montesquieu), [*The Spirit of Laws*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spirit_of_Law), 1748. Archive.org has several editions of the classic 1750 translation by [Thomas Nugent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Nugent_(travel_writer)): [volume 1](https://archive.org/details/spiritoflaws01montuoft), [volume 2](https://archive.org/details/spiritoflaws02montuoft). (With an essay by W. Bagehot.) Read it online, using Wikipedia whenever you don't understand something. Allocate about 2 months.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Aristotle's *Politics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_(Aristotle)) or [Plato's *Republic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_(Plato)).  These are the source of ideas very widely disseminated in Western sources and will therefore at least *seem* comprehensive.  Now there are some caveats to using these - the ancient setting and way of writing is off-putting, and we use many of the terms differently than they did.  (For example, "democracy" means a mob rule more like the riots for George Floyd in Minneapolis and Donald Trump at the Capitol, while "aristocracy" might be applied to the mainland Chinese system assessing socialist virtue)  It may well be more satisfying to use brief summaries you find online (and be honest, who doesn't...).

When creating your countries, I don't think you have to be tremendously accurate.  Look around at modern politics - very few people on any side are doing things that make much sense given their personal self-interest or logical or moral systems of thought.  Be a provocateur and let your imagination off the leash.